# Easy way to explain the difference between rel and type in html tags

Tags: html, css

What is an easy way to explain the difference between the attributes `rel` and `type` in html tags?

Here's an example:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
```

And why are both needed?  In the above example, there seems to be a pretty strong overlap between the two.

Bonus - is there an explanation of how are these tags used by the browser that would help one understand the need for both of these attributes in the above `<link>` example?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute describes the data format the link points to. "This is a Windows Icon file", "This is a PNG image", "This is an HTML document".

The `rel` attribute describes what connection (relationship) it has to the current document. "This is to be displayed as the Favicon", "This is the next document in a sequence", "This is another document that has the same content as this one but in a different format".

Answer (score 3):

`type` defines the [MIME *type*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Media_Type), whereas `rel` defines the *relation* to the document.

MIME types [include](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) image/png, text/plain, application/json, ….

Possible [relation types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) include stylesheet, icon, author, help, ….